# Change Image with toggle button

Tags: java, android, toggle

I am new to Android developing. I managed to do a task to change an image for clicking two different buttons.

My `MainActivity.java`:

```
package com.example.sandorhorvath.imageviewchange;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public void lightBox(View view) {
       ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
       image.setImageResource(R.drawable.kawa2);
    }

    public void lightBox1(View view) {
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.kawa1);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

I want to keep the code really simple and make the same with one button I tried with toggle but I can identify the onClick with `lightBox` but where should I identify the `lightBox2`? I can turn on the function but I don't find the off function value.

Comment: explain what do you want exactly

Comment: Have a same function but with one button. Now its working with two buttons on the screen. I want to make it workable with one toggle button.To make it more accurate where should I identify identify the "lightbox" and "lightbox1" in toggle?

Comment: your app will only have one toggle button..and each click will change the image ryt ??

Comment: Yes exactly but i dont know where to identify when its on already or pressed in a normal button have onClick value is lightBox and lightbox1 but where goes in toggle the lightBox1

Comment: i have updated the logic try it and update if it works..

Comment: check the update please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this logic for toggling image with only one button ...write this in click func

```
boolean check = false;

public void lightBox(View view) {

 if(check) {
 image
.setImageResource(R.drawable.kawa1                                          ); 
 check = false;}
else {
 image
.setImageResource(R.drawable.kawa2                                        ); 
 check = true;}

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Working like a charm a little modification added to the code the image had to be defined.

```
boolean check = false;

public void lightBox(View view) {
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    if(check) {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.kawa1);
        check = false;
    } else {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.kawa2);
        check = true;
    }

 }
```

Thank you for your help! The logic is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android.support.design.widget.CheckableImageButton` from the support design library like this:

```
         <android.support.design.widget.CheckableImageButton
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textOn="@null"
             android:textOff="@null"
             android:background="@null"
             android:src="@drawable/your_image"/>
```